# How to know whether the host DNS address is static configure or dynamic gain through windows API(or c++ code)?

Tags: c++, windows, dns

I wanna get whether the host DNS is static or dynamic in my code, but I didn't find any API can get this, how can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by static or dynamic DNS?

Comment: I mean, Obtain DNS Server Address automatically == dynamic, not Obtain DNS Server Address automatically == static

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know which interface you want, the `netioapi.h` header contains the function

```cpp
NETIOAPI_API GetInterfaceDnsSettings(
  GUID                   Interface,
  DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS *Settings
);
```

which returns a `DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS` struct. That struct contains the member variable `ULONG64 Flags` in which bit 0x8 states whether or not dynamic DNS registration is enabled for the given adapter.

For more info checkout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-getinterfacednssettings

Comment: “dynamic DNS registration” means Obtain DNS Server Address automatically？

Comment: I believe so. Though to be honest I am a little fuzzy on the nomenclature in this area, so I defiantly could be wrong.